# Critical values for a projection map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $X\in R^3$ and $f(x,y,z) = x^2+3y^2-z^2-xy+2z$, then $df_{(x,y,z)} = (2x-y, 6y-x, 2-2z)$ and the tangent space $TX = \{(a,b,c) \in R^3 | (2x-y)a+(6y-x)b+(2-2z)c=0\}$. Now let $g:R^3\rightarrow R$ s.t. $g((x,y,z))=z$. I am trying to find the critical values of $g$. I know

$dg_{(x,y,z)}:TX_{(x,y,z)}\rightarrow R$

So $dg_{(x,y,z)}$ will be surjective provided that $TX\neq R^2\times \{0\}$, i.e. when $c=0$, because $dg_{(x,y,z)}$ projects the third coordinate. But I am stumped as to how to get a condition on $x,y,z$ such that $dg_{(x,y,z)}$ is not surjective and thus find critical values. A hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $$X = \{(x,y,z)\in {\mathbb R}^3 \mid f(x,y,z)= 0\}?$$ If so, do you mean to view $g$ as the restriction to $X$, i.e., as $$ g\colon X \to {\mathbb R}?$$

Comment: If so, if $f(x,y,z)  = 0$, then $$ TX_{x,y,z} = \{ (a,b,c)\in {\mathbb R}^3 \mid df_{(x,y,z)} (a-x,b-y,c-z) = 0 \},$$ which does not quite agree with what you wrote above...

Comment: Assuming that I have understood what you want: "geometrically," a critical point happen when the corresponding tangent plane of $X$ is PARALLEL to the $x-y$ plane. That means that its normal is parallel to the $z$-axis: the $x$ and $y$ components of the normal are $0$. So you want to solve $f= f_x = f_y = 0$. OK?